# Dynamic unpivoting in Oracle

Tags: oracle, unpivot

I create a view that unpivots my wide table. I do this:

```
CREATE VIEW MYLONGTABLE AS 
SELECT *
FROM   MYWIDETABLE
UNPIVOT (VALUE FOR PARAMETER IN (
            PARAM1,
            PARAM2,
            [continues with ~200 entries]
));
```

Now, the list `PARAM1, PARAM2, ...` should be calculated dynamically. What is the easiest way to do this? An inner `SELECT` won't work, unfortunately. This would be easiest for me, because I have the `PARAM`s stored in another table.

Comment: Have you tried dynamic query?

Comment: @Avi: thanks, I will [try it](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48393/passing-column-names-dynamically-to-unpivot).